# Hibernate with two databases

Tags: java, hibernate

If my Hibernate have to interact with two database then I need two SessionFactory to be created. (I hope this is the only way to do it. If there is any other please let me know)

Now the question is if a transaction has to be performed which includes both the database then how will it be achieved?

Any help will be great.

Comment: google for `hibernate distributed transaction`

Comment: Read up on [2PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) and check that your JDBC driver and database support this protocol.

Comment: you will have to use JTA

Answer (score 0):

Please look Hibernate Shards.........

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/shards/3.0/reference/en/html_single/